# How to write a GPU parallelization program that will run on any GPU?

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, gpu, opencl

I have worked with Halide and Cuda. However, a technology like CUDA will only run on NVIDIA GPUs. OpenCL will also run on AMD cards but there is no real all-in-one solution as far as I know.

But software like for example Matlab runs on any OS, independently of which GPU is in there. I believe Matlab uses parallellization techniques to speed up calculations on matrices (or at least I hope so).

So how does one go about writing a piece of software that can use the GPU for parallellizing calculations without writing separate software for each possible type of GPU? Or is this actually the only way to go?

I'm not planning to write such an application any time soon, I just became curious after taking a course on the subject.

Comment: https://www.khronos.org/conformance/adopters/conformant-products/opencl OpenCL seems what you are looking for.

Comment: Write it in [SYCL](https://www.khronos.org/sycl/) and wait a couple of years. Or try your luck at [HIP](https://github.com/ROCm-Developer-Tools/HIP) for two out of three.

Comment: @FelipeGutierrez I don't think so. That's what I said in my post, it only has real support for NVIDIA and AMD.

Comment: @tera but will it still run on any GPU you think?

Comment: Not any CPU, and certainly not now.

Comment: Why am I getting downvotes? It's a good question.. If there are no solutions yet that cover all GPUs that doesn't make it a useless question.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be wrong about matlab supporting any gpu it is uses cuda for nividea gpus
see : https://www.mathworks.com/solutions/gpu-computing.html
and: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/336084-will-matlab-support-amd-gpu-in-future

To answer your question

It seems like the 2 options are:

OpenCL : https://www.khronos.org/opencl/

DirectCompute/compute-shader : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/direct3d-11-advanced-stages-compute-shader

OpenCL is cross platform and DirectCompute is windows only and build on DirectX

Comment: But will that work on any modern (say 2015+) GPU?

Comment: A modern GPU should work for both. Maybe for directComptute you can't use the newest version for a card from 2015.
OpenCL also has support for other multi core devices such as CPUs,DSPs,FPGAs.

Comment: I should add there is specialized hardware that wouldn't work with this but it's likely Matlab wouldn't support them either.

Comment: OpenGL also supports compute.

Comment: @FelipeGutierrez yes, but as far as I could see DirectCompute isn't cross platform right?

Comment: AFAIK it doesn't even work on OpenGL ES and only from > 4 if I remember correctly.

Comment: OpenGL compute is from version 4.5 if I remember, but that should not be a problem for modern GPU.